# Inverse Laplace transformation of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

Consider the complex function $\displaystyle f(s)=\frac{1}{\frac lc\sqrt{(s(s+r_0)}}$ where $r_0, l, c$ are positive real number and s is a complex variable. How I can obtain the inverse Laplace transformation of this function?

Comment: See [this solution][1] and set $a=0$.


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368963/find-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-complex-function/369332#369332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following formula about my question. 
$$L^{-1}\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{s+a}\sqrt{s+b}}\}=e^{-\frac{(a+b)t}{2}}I_0(\frac{a-b}{2}t)$$
where $I_0(x)$ is modified Bessel function.
But I have another question. I put it in this site. It would be grateful if someone can help me.

Thanks